# Stratum level of the clock on any networking device

Tags: networking, ntp

We all know that a networking device operates at various stratum levels.  How can we find out the stratum level of the clock at which the device operates? I have an embedded networking device that monitors the network traffic. How can I find out the stratum level of the clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on how much information your embedded device provides. Generally, if it is running NTP and it provides some kind of debug output - it should be there. Alternatively, point your embedded device to receive NTP data from a well known NTP server with fixed stratum and then your stratum will be stratum_of_that_server + 1.

EDIT: Page 18 of [NTPv4 protocol spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5905.txt) shows the format of the packet. Stratum is 4th field in a packet.

Comment: Will I be able to extract the data related to stratum from the NTP packets?